# Aptana 3 for populating a blank file with HTML using HTML:5 command

Tags: aptana

I am semi new to Aptana Studio 3. I have been using it for a couple months now, and I just saw a video tutorial where a guy typed in html:5 in a blank file, and it populated it with the HTML doc tag, header info, etc..

Is this a plug-in for aptana? or does it come with it out of the box... I tried typing it in a blank file, but nothing happened.

Seems pretty neat and fast!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are referring to zen-coding at:

http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/

There is a plugin for Eclipse/Aptana.

HTH

-Rob B.

Comment: That's exactly what it was... This rocks!! Thank you!